# Thingworx - How to read/write client cookies from a mashup or service

Tags: cookies, thingworx

How to read/write cookies to a local computer when opening a Thingworx mashup

Comment: You could elaborate the question, adding details regarding the usecase and about the entities would benefit

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the ThingWorx platform first of all.

Can you describe your use-case in more detail (why are you trying to read/write cookies)? 
This functionality is not required when using the Mashup Builder to create/update mashups (based on my experience).  I am quite curious to see the reason you need to do this.